# C# How to declare a reference variable to store the address of an object

Tags: c#

I just need a basic understanding of reference variables as I am in a basic class.  My professor wants us to declare a reference variable to store the address of an object and I don't know how to do that or really what that even does.

He did teach us how to do something like this.

```
    public double Method(ref name)
```

But I don't get how that's supposed to store the 'address' of the object.

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [ref (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: the address is unsafe code.

Comment: you can get a reference to a value by casting it into an `object`. There are value types and reference types in C# and there is _never_ a reason you should worry about the address of an object.

Comment: You say "address of the object", that's just a normal reference in .NET. `string s = "10";` here `s` is a variable holding a reference (the address of) the string object containing `"10"`. Please clarify what your professor asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
public static double SeName0(MyType new_name)
{
    new_name = new MyType(); // only new_name reference to a new object
}

public static double SeName1(ref MyType new_name)
{
    new_name = new MyType(); // both name and ref new_name reference to a new object
}

public static void Main()
{
   MyType name;
   SeName0(name); // Do not touch name variable in this local scope
   SeName1(name); // Change name reference to new object
}
```

Let's imagine a stack program:

[image]

The thin arrow shows that **ref name** takes address of original **name** and at the same time is a reference to the same object.
If you call only functions on object nothing happens.
But if you change **ref name** reference to another object then the original reference **name** changes either.

Answer (score 0):

The questions is a bit vague though, he may be simply checking whether you understand reference types and value types in C# which is far more important in my view than understanding the usage of ref keyword on method parameters.

With that it is no harm to mention, value types are stored on the stack and reference types are stored on the managed heap memory. Their address gets stored in the stack as value type and that is called the reference.

Below you instantiate an object, that is reference type and created on the heap. obj1 contains the reference, value of the pointer to the managed heap.

Object obj1 = new Object();

Below you declare another reference type variable called obj2. You do not instantiate it this time, you just assign the value of the obj1 reference to obj2.

Object obj2 = obj1;

And that may be what your prof was asking you. Even if that s not the case still good to know:)